# Add or Update a field in one JSON file from another JSON file based on matching field

Tags: json, jq

I have two JSON files `a.json` and `b.json`. The contents in a.json file is a JSON object and inside b.json its an array.I want to add/update `status` field in each `mappings` in a.json by retrieving the value from b.json file.
a.json:

```
{
  "title": 25886,
  "data": {
    "request": {
      "c": 46369,
      "t1": 1562050127.376641
    },
  },
  "rs": {
    "mappings": {
      "12345": {
        "id": "12345",
        "name": "test",
        "customer_id": "11228",
      },
      "45678": {
        "id": "45678",
        "name": "abc",
        "customer_id": "11206",
      }
    }
}}
```

b.json:

```
[
  {
    "status": "pending",
    "extra": {
      "name": "test"
    },
    "enabled": true,
    "id": "12345"
  },
  {
    "status": "not_started",
    "extra": {
      "name": "abc"
    },
    "enabled": true,
    "id": "45678"
  }
]
```

Below is my expected output:

```
{
  "title": 25886,
  "data": {
    "request": {
      "c": 46369,
      "t1": 1562050127.376641
    },
  },
  "rs": {
    "mappings": {
      "12345": {
        "id": "12345",
        "name": "test",
        "customer_id": "11228",
        "status":"pending"
      },
      "45678": {
        "id": "45678",
        "name": "abc",
        "customer_id": "11206",
        "status":"not_started"
      }
    }
}}
```

In this expected JSON file we have `status` field whose value is retrieved from b.json file based on a matching `id` value. How to do this using `jq` ?

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of this problem, b.json essentially defines a dictionary, so for simplicity, efficiency and perhaps elegance,
it make sense to start by using the builtin function `INDEX` to create the relevant dictionary:

```
INDEX( $b[] | {id, status}; .id )
```

This assumes an invocation of jq along the lines of:

```
jq --argfile b b.json -f update.jq a.json
```

(Yes, I know `--argfile` has been deprecated.  Feel free to choose another way to set $b to the contents of b.json.)

Now, to perform the update, it will be simplest to use the "update" operator, `|=`, in conjunction with `map_values`. (Feel free to check the jq manual :-)

Putting everything together:

```
INDEX( $b[] | {id, status}; .id ) as $dict
| .rs.mappings |= map_values( .status = $dict[.id].status )
```

Comment: jq --argfile b b.json -f  a.json | INDEX( $b[] | {id, status}; .id ) as $dict | .rs.mappings |= map_values( .status = $dict[.id].status )
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `$b[]'

Comment: jq --argfile b b.json -f update.jq a.json | INDEX( $b[] | {id, status}; .id ) as $dict | .rs.mappings |= map_values( .status = $dict[.id].status )
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `$b[]'

Comment: @dks551 if you're passing the `jq` script as a parameter to the `jq` command you should 1) remove the `-f` flag which specifies a file to read the `jq` script from ; 2) quote the `jq` script with single-quotes so that `bash` doesn't expand `$vars` ; 3) put the `a.json` file after the `jq` script. Something like `jq --argfile b b.json 'INDEX( $b[] | {id, status}; .id ) as $dict | .rs.mappings |= map_values( .status = $dict[.id].status )' a.json`